# async.parallel doesn't wait for the parallel functions

Tags: node.js, async.js

Running the code bellow I just get "undefined". It seems like the async.parallel call executes the final function before the 4 parallel functions are finished.

```
function classify(filename) {
    var stack = [];

    var functionOne = async function(callback){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierOne(filename);
        callback(null, res);
    }
    var functionTwo = async function(callback){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierTwo(filename);
        callback(null, res);
    }
    var functionThree = async function(callback){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierThree(filename);
        callback(null, res);
    }
    var functionFour = async function(callback){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierFour(filename);
        callback(null, res);
    }

    stack.push(functionOne);
    stack.push(functionTwo);
    stack.push(functionThree);
    stack.push(functionFour);

    async.parallel(stack, function(err, res){
        console.log(res[0]);
    })
}
```

Comment: try using
await Promise.all(stack) @Marc B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `async` with version `3.x`, we have a big change - [Support async/await](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v300) , with the version, with tasks which have been wrap to a Promise (when you use async/await keyword) then the `callback` will be disable, you need to return value in the tasks instead of call `callback(null, value)`.

This mean, to fix your case, the code will come to:

```
function classify(filename) {
    var stack = [];

    var functionOne = async function(){ // remove callback param
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierOne(filename);
        return res; // return value
    }
    var functionTwo = async function(){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierTwo(filename);
        return res;
    }
    var functionThree = async function(){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierThree(filename);
        return res;
    }
    var functionFour = async function(){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierFour(filename);
        return res;
    }

    stack.push(functionOne);
    stack.push(functionTwo);
    stack.push(functionThree);
    stack.push(functionFour);

    async.parallel(stack, function(err, res){
        console.log(res[0]);
    })
}
```

P/s: My suggestion is using Promise.all for this case. Say no to `callback`.

```
async function classify(filename) { // Make this function become a async function
    var stack = [];

    var functionOne = async function(){ // remove callback param
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierOne(filename);
        return res; // return value
    }
    var functionTwo = async function(){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierTwo(filename);
        return res;
    }
    var functionThree = async function(){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierThree(filename);
        return res;
    }
    var functionFour = async function(){
        //call to an API
        res = await classifierFour(filename);
        return res;
    }

    stack.push(functionOne);
    stack.push(functionTwo);
    stack.push(functionThree);
    stack.push(functionFour);

    const result = await Promise.all(stack); // Wait until all "task" finish
    console.log(result);
    return result; // Return the result of all tasks
}

// Call classify function inner a async function
const result = await classify('your_file_name'); // await keyword
console.log(result);
```

Comment: THis  works and res[0] will be printed. But I want the whole function to return the result after all finished. Something like: 
...
answer = await async.parallel(stack, function(err, res){
   return res;
})
return answer;
...

Useing this code the return will just be undefined.

Comment: It's because ```classifierFour``` etc is not defined in the code. also there is no need for ```res```, you return directly, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about the `async` npm library but on top of it looks like it doesn't work when you have a callback function as `async`. If you try it using native promises, it will work. Something like

```
function classify(filename) {
  var stack = [];

  var functionOne = function(callback) {
    //call to an API
    classifierOne(filename).then(res => callback(null, res));
  };
  var functionTwo = function(callback) {
    classifierTwo(filename).then(res => callback(null, res));
  };
  var functionThree = function(callback) {
    classifierThree(filename).then(res => callback(null, res));
  };
  var functionFour = function(callback) {
    classifierFour(filename).then(res => callback(null, res));
  };

  stack.push(functionOne);
  stack.push(functionTwo);
  stack.push(functionThree);
  stack.push(functionFour);
  async.parallel(stack, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methods like i.e. `functionOne` missed the return and didn't a callback. The below returns `["1","2","3","4"]`.

```
const async = require('async');

const classifierOne   = async ()=> "1"
const classifierTwo   = async ()=> "2"
const classifierThree = async ()=> "3"
const classifierFour  = async ()=> "4"

const classify = filename => {
    var stack = [];

    var functionOne   = async ()=> classifierOne(filename);
    var functionTwo   = async ()=> classifierTwo(filename);
    var functionThree = async ()=> classifierThree(filename);
    var functionFour  = async ()=> classifierFour(filename);


    stack.push(functionOne);
    stack.push(functionTwo);
    stack.push(functionThree);
    stack.push(functionFour);

    async.parallel(stack, (err, res)=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
}

classify("x");
```